# how to know new jar dependencies

Tags: java, jar, hbase, presto, apache-phoenix

we have presto cluster with 35 presto Linux workers nodes

we want to add new jar - `phoenix-server-client-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.jar` to `plugin/phoenix` folder

while the current jars that related to phoenix in this folder are

```
phoenix-client-4.14.1-HBase-1.4-embedded.jar
presto-phoenix-317.jar
```

while all the other jars in folder comes with scratch presto installation

we try to add only the jar - `phoenix-server-client-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.jar` to folder - `plugin/phoenix`

but when we send new presto query we get the error about

```
Newer Phoenix clients can't communicate with older Phoenix servers. The following servers require an updated phoenix-[version]-server.jar to be put in the class path of HBase:
```

Comment: reading the release notes?

Comment: not succesed top fined release notes with all dependencies that are needed

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but you may also try asking on `#dev` in [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).